MPI Program having issues when allocating memory with malloc
So i have this code
#define N 5

int i, j, rank, numprocs, rows, extra_rows;
float *matrix, *matrixAux;
float vector[N];
float *result, *resultAux;
struct timeval tv1, tv2;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

rows = ceil(N / numprocs);
extra_rows = (N % numprocs != 0 && rank == numprocs - 1) ? (numprocs * rows - N) : 0;

if ((matrixAux = malloc(sizeof(float) * (rows + extra_rows) * N)) == NULL)
    perror("error 1: ");
if ((resultAux = malloc(sizeof(float) * (rows + extra_rows))) == NULL)
    perror("error 2: ");

The situation is that I have a matrix and I have to calculate the result of multiplying it by a vector, so different processes only have to calculate isolated parts of the matrix and then gather everything together to have the final result. My problem resides in the fact that when I'm calculating the extra rows that I may have to assign to a process, if this extra rows aren't 0 then the malloc fails and I don't know why.
Here is the output for N = 5, it fails when allocating the memory for matrixAux,
error 1: : Cannot allocate memory
error 2: : Cannot allocate memory
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] *** Process received signal ***
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] Failing at address: (nil)
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42990)[0x77aa96242990]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x17d76c)[0x77aa9637d76c]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.40(opal_convertor_unpack+0xbe)[0x77aa960ce69e]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 3] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_recv_frag_callback_match+0x43f)[0x77aa94187fef]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 4] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so(mca_btl_vader_poll_handle_frag+0x95)[0x77aa94331c25]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 5] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_btl_vader.so(+0x7f74)[0x77aa94331f74]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 6] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.40(opal_progress+0x34)[0x77aa960b7e24]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 7] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_recv+0x325)[0x77aa9418cc35]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 8] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_coll_tuned.so(ompi_coll_tuned_scatter_intra_dec_fixed+0x68)[0x77aa9412e4a8]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [ 9] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40(PMPI_Scatter+0x102)[0x77aa9651c582]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [10] main(+0x174f)[0x619ab24af74f]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [11] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x28150)[0x77aa96228150]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [12] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x89)[0x77aa96228209]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] [13] main(+0x1225)[0x619ab24af225]
[user-NBR-WAX9:18067] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 2 with PID 0 on node user-NBR-WAX9 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Code of the program:
#define N 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i, j, rank, numprocs, rows, extra_rows;
    float *matrix, *matrixAux;
    float vector[N];
    float *result, *resultAux;
    struct timeval tv1, tv2;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    rows = ceil(N / numprocs);
    extra_rows = (N % numprocs != 0 && rank == numprocs - 1) ? (numprocs * rows - N) : 0;

    if ((matrixAux = malloc(sizeof(float) * (rows + extra_rows) * N)) == NULL)
        perror("error 1: ");
    if ((resultAux = malloc(sizeof(float) * (rows + extra_rows))) == NULL)
        perror("error 2: ");

    /* Initialize Matrix and Vector */
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        if ((matrix = malloc(sizeof(float) * N * N)) == NULL)
            perror("error 3: ");
        if ((result = malloc(sizeof(float) * N)) == NULL)
            perror("error 4: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            vector[i] = i;

            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                matrix[i * N + j] = i + j;
            }
        }
        print_matrix1(rank, N, matrix);
    }
    MPI_Scatter(matrix, N * rows, MPI_FLOAT, matrixAux, N * rows, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(vector, N, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank != 2)
        print_matrix1(rank, rows, matrixAux);
    else
        print_matrix1(rank, rows + (numprocs * rows - N), matrixAux);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {

        resultAux[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            resultAux[i] += matrixAux[i * N + j] * vector[j];
        }
    }

    MPI_Gather(resultAux, rows, MPI_FLOAT, result, rows, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /*Display result */

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            printf(" %f \t ", result[i]);
        }
        free(matrix);
        free(result);
    }
    free(matrixAux);
    free(resultAux);
    MPI_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}


What are the values of rows and extra_rows? Print them out before you try to allocate menory.

when I have 3 processes and N = 5, for the process 0 and 1 -> rows = 1, extra_rows = 0               For the process 2 -> rows = 1, extra_rows = 2

So in the first process you allocate space for 5 elements ((1 + 0) * N == 5). In the second process you allocate space for 3 elements (1 + 2). That shouldn't be a problem, which means there's a problem elsewhere in your code. So please try to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

I added the program code after removing some lines that doesn't affect anything since is not a very long program

You have multiple malloc() calls. I don't see a way to differentiate them as you only say error to all of them instead of perror("error matrixAux: ");, perror("error resultAux: "); etc. You said "Here is the output for N = 5, it fails when allocating the memory for matrixAux" but are you 100% sure or guessing? Did you try debugging and stepping through the code?

I saw your comment and changed it, I edited the question code and I compiled and executed the program and the output was what I expected. I was not guessing because I debugged a lot to know what was happening but you are right, the same perror line wasn't very clever

And just what do you think rows = ceil(N / numprocs); sets rows to for N = 5 and, say, numprocs = 8?

Thank you for the edit! I haven't used MPI so I looked up some info. The MPI* functions are not void, their return type is an error code (int) so I recommend you update the code and put an int mpi_err on each MPI*() call and then output the value and see if any returns anything other than MPI_SUCCESS. I am not saying it is necessarily the case, but it's good practice to not assume a pleasant run on all of the code all the time, but expect some errors and handle them (or at least "crash" gracefully). When you say you have 3 processes, you mean you run it 3 times? And numprocs = 3?

mpirun noticed that process rank 2 with PID 0 on node user-NBR-WAX9 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault) . Wait, how is the second process with PID 0? Am I misunderstanding something here? Shouldn't rank 0 (or 1, depending if the count is zero-based) be PID 0?

by default, most MPI functions will abort the code if they do not return MPI_SUCCESS. When asking a question, always post code that can be compiled (the #include are missing), and include your mpirun command line. just print rows and extra_rows when malloc() fails and see what you missed.
